# Service Builder Liferay Relationships

Tags: many-to-many, liferay, crud, liferay-service-builder

I have "Storage" portlet:
[image]

I can click "Add Book":

[image]

But I need to have opportunity to add author's name to my book. So I created new project, new Service Builder with new entity "author", and now I can add author too. But how can I make dropdown menu with existing authors when I click "add book"? How can I bind that field with new table - "author"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create another project for the author, in the same service builder as the book entity add author entity and  add reference to another table that will hold the primary key's of book and author.
`service.xml` could be:

```
<service-builder package-path="com.myproject.db">
<author>SO</author>
<namespace>myp</namespace>
<entity name="Book" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
<column name="bookId" type="long" primary="true" />
<column name="name" type="String" />
<column name="description" type="String" />
<column name="price" type="long" />
<column name="author" type="Collection" entity="Author" mapping-table="Author_Books"/>
</entity>
<entity name="Author" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
<column name="authorId" type="long" primary="true" />
<column name="authorName" type="String" />
<column name="books" type="Collection" entity="Book" mapping-table="Author_Books" />
</entity>
</service-builder>
```

And when you deploy this portlet it will create another table `myp_Author_Books` that will have composite key of `authorId` and `bookId`.
Than in your rendering method of book form add

`List<Author> authorList=AuthorLocalServiceUtil.getAuthor(0,     AuthorLocalServiceUtil.getAuthorCount());
renderRequest.addAttribute("listAuthor",authorList )`

and use this attribute in jsp with `c:forEach` and `aui:select` to create your dropdown, smth like:

```
<aui:select name="author" label="Author Name">
    <c:forEach var="currAuthor" items="${listAuthor}">
        <aui:option value="${currAuthor.authorId}" label=" ${student.authorName}"></aui:option>
    </c:forEach>
</aui:select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I vote you up! But I still have one question: what should I paste instead of `<aui:input name="authorName" label="Author Name"/>` to make dropdown? Im a newbie so I can't get it

Comment: Just edited my answer to give a clue on the jsp part, hope that helps!

Comment: Am I wrong if I am saying that this models a many-to-many relationship ? Even though it is practical in this scenario, how would a one-to-many relationship be modeled? I mean, let's suppose I want a Person to have multiple Addresses (one is home address, another is work address, etc) - how should I map this ? One way may be with a Collection setting that will return an array with them, but what if I want to have multiple fields in the Person's Entity and each field to be a FK from the Address Entity ? Is it possible ?